# Why can I call a function from another file (with warning) but cannot use a variable from another file without declaring it?

Tags: c

```c
// a.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d", sum());
}
```

```c
// b.c 
int sum() {
   return 10;
}
```

I compile those two files with
`gcc a.c b.c` normally, it works fine with an `implicit declaration` warning and this warning disappears if I declare `sum` in `a.c`. I've read in another post that it is fine if I don't declare the function and if I call it properly, but it's not advised to do so and I should always declare what I use in each file, and this is fine and understandable.

What I don't understand is why there's a distinction between functions defined in another file and variables. Why can't I use a variable defined in another file in the same manner as above? I can also get it to run by declaring `i` in the file where I use it, though.

```c
// c.c 
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("%d", i);
    return ;
}
```

```c
// d.c 
int i = 12;
```

compiled with `gcc c.c d.c`, produces the following error

```
c.c: In function ‘main’:
c.c:3:19: error: ‘i’ undeclared (first use in this function)
      printf("%d", i);
                   ^
c.c:3:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Comment: It's hard to answer a question "why is something not there". It's not there because... it's not there.

Comment: @KamilCuk I won't say that I expected more, to be honest. I just thought I might ask to see if there's a reasoning behind it that I do not get. :)

Comment: I believe that should be a warning and `i` will default to `extern int`. Maybe the compiler flags say "treat warnings as errors"

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I did not give it any flags, and the same machine and settings were used to compile `a.c` and `b.c` and It gave a warning and compiled anyway, so I don't think that it is treating a warning as an error.

Comment: @user3121023 It gives the same warning, and compiles, but as I've read in other posts, it assumes that it returns an `int`. If I change the `printf` specifier to `%f`, it gives another warning that I'm giving it an `int`, i.e. the return value of `sum`, but `%f` expects a double.  Also, it prints 0, not 10.0.

Comment: I think your question could technically be rephrased to: "*Why `i` is not visible in `c.c` although declared to be `extern` in `d.c`?*" to get directly on-point.

Comment: @TortelliniTeusday Also: Do you ask in the context of the C standard?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio I did not declare anything to be extern, I just thought that I can use variables that are defined elsewhere without declaring them just like functions, but apparently I just can't, and the reasons are justified, of course, I think that it's more like functions should not be callable without declaration, not variables should be referencable without declarations like functions.

Comment: @TortelliniTeusday "*I did not declare anything to be extern*"- `i` in `d.c` is `extern`al linkage by default since it is defined at global scope and any storage class specifier is omitted. This is an automatic process.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Ah yes, I think that your rephrasing is correct now, yes. I had it in mind somewhat backwards, I thought at first that you meant `i` declared `extern` in `c.c` to be able to use it while defined in another file, because people tend to call what you meant _external linkage_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the "implicit int" rule is long gone (since C99) and there's no case for *not* providing declarations in modern C (i.e. C99 and later).

---

However, why functions are OK with implicit declarations but not variables is because that's how it was initially defined in the pre-standard C (impplicit rules were valid in C89, too).

From Dennis Ritchie's [C reference manual](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cman.pdf):

> 13. Implicit declarations
>
> It is not always necessary to specify both the storage class and the type of identifiers in a declaration.
> Sometimes the storage class is supplied by the context: in external
> definitions, and in declarations of formal parameters and structure
> members. In a declaration inside a function, if a storage class but no
> type is given, the identifier is assumed to be int; if a type but no
> storage class is indicated, the identifier is assumed to be auto. An
> exception to the latter rule is made for functions, since auto
> functions are meaningless (C being incapable of compiling code into
> the stack). **If the type of an identifier is ‘‘function returning
> ...’’, it is implicitly declared to be extern. In an expression, an
> identifier followed by ( and not currently declared is contextually
> declared to be ‘‘function returning int’’.**
>
> **Undefined identifiers not followed by ( are assumed to be labels which will be defined later in the function. (Since a label is not an
> lvalue, this accounts for the ‘‘Lvalue required’’ error message
> sometimes noticed when an undeclared identifier is used.) Naturally,
> appearance of an identifier as a label declares it as such.**

(emphasis mine)

That means the following are OK:

```
// assumed to return int
func()
{
    return 0;
}


// Type of 'some_var' defaults to int
void func2(some_var)
{
}
```

But this is not OK:

```
int func()
{
    // Assumed to be labels; it's undeclared variable.
    i;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

History, mostly. Early C was very lax (sloppy) in ways that continue the pain down to this day. The base K&R book was also vague in many points that the first ANSI standard firmed up when the committee aware of confusion points produced it. I consider using any extern without declaring it bad practice. Suspect this came about because languages like FORTRAN had no function declarations in it's early days and no external variables at all (not counting COMMON as externals). It can also depend on the warning level (if you are using gnu gcc try under -Wall).

C also has something called a "tentative definition" where a declaration without `extern` can happen that may have contributed to the decisions.

Functions had default declarations (returns od integer, arguments as given) but variables would be a little more risky, given the way C freely converts data types. If you want to test this throw an `int i;` into c.c and a `float i = 12;` into d.c.

Comment: It is not right to say early C was sloppy. Modern notions of language structure and features did not exist. People were not neglecting established rules or principles or good practice; they were creating new things out of nothing. The early workings of C may have been loose by today’s standards, but it is not fair to judge past creators as “sloppy” by today’s standards.

Comment: @EricPostpischil — 'lax' rather than 'sloppy', but by the time C was first released, there were languages like Algol-60 and Algol-68, and PL/1, and Pascal (1970).  C deliberately chose a different path from those (especially Algol-68), but there were precedents before C was produced.

Comment: Historical C was lax in letting people use undeclared functions, only assuming an `int` return type. Today's C compilers are sloppy in accepting such programs today when the behavior is explicitly specified as undefined in the C Standard. Such sloppiness is easy to fix with appropriate compiler options such as `-Wall -Werror`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  JonathanLeffler chqrlie I'll go with "lax" though,way back when K&R was the bible, I was disappointed on several fronts with C, including the default prototypes. Even in the late 70s I had learned that lesson with other languages, like the (these days) much maligned COBOL, I had used that fataled out on such things, It greatly reduced run-time debugging.  (lack of financial support and the K&R prototypes were other points). Don't get me wrong, I really liked C at the time but I could see where it could of been made better from day-one.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - those other languages you mentioned - Algol, PL/1, Pascal - were  very much do-everything "poor-little-programmer-let-me-hold-your hand" languages. C was designed from the get-go as a minimalist "you're-a-professional-we-trust-you" language.I'm not saying one approach is necessarily better than the other, but notice which language is still heavily used in 2020 and which ones are not.